# Rails: How to implement find* for an abstract class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a legacy DB where two rather similar object types are stored in different tables, with different columns and relations. There's a parent class used for bridging the gap, but I'm at a bit of a loss how to implement it to emulate the child classes. Ideally, methods like `find_all_by_*` should run on both subclasses and return all the results in a single array. Is there some canonical way to do this, simpler than copying [the code of `find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find)?

Comment: How about creating a view in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, interesting question. Not sure if there's a better solution than this, but I'd use a bit of method missing magic.

```
class MyVirtualModel 

  def respond_to?(method, include_private = false)
    if method.to_s =~ /^find.*/
      RealModel1.respond_to?(method, include_private) && RealModel2.respond_to?(method, include_private?)
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def method_missing(method, *arguments, &block)
    if method.to_s =~ /^find.*/
      resultset1 = RealModel1.send(method, arguments)
      resultset2 = RealModel2.send(method, arguments)
      return resultset1 + resultset2
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Neat solution, but it looks like that whole block is bypassed: `PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "" does not exist`. `binding.pry` in both methods didn't help - They are not called by the Rails web server.